# How can I keep my objects or groups as particles level on the field

Tags: particles

I'm making a forest along hills. I managed to setup my particles to follow the topology, but when I add more objects into the group, the new objects float above the topology randomly. Of course I have it set to random, but the altitude should be along the topology. How can I fix that? The objects that are duplicated are slightly below 0 on the z axis and then they are selected as the group to set for the particle.

Comment: Have you made sure that the origins for each object aren’t set below their mesh?

Comment: Is your Particle `Type` set to `Emitter`, or `Hair`? :)